# Converting Swift self.navigationItem.title = show.uppercased()

Tags: xcode, error-handling, swift3

Hi I have this code right now but im getting an error message. It says,

Value of type '(UIViewController, Any? -> Void' has no member 'uppercased'

```
 // title at the top
    self.navigationItem.title = show.uppercased()
```

could someone please help me. Thanks

Comment: It depends on other parts of your code. Please show how your `show`s are declared. (Including both properties and methods.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls Declare the show variable like this:

```
var show:String = "title"

self.navigationItem.title = show.uppercased()
```